# Oracle, finding data between two different dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table name as business_details and column name business_date whose data type is varchar2.

Now i have to find out the data between two different dates and date format like : 12-JUN-18 21:15:13

Means, 12 Jun, 2018.

Kindly help me to write a query which can fetch the data between these two dates :12-JUN-18 21:15:13 and 25-JUN-18 18:15:32

Comment: Convert to date using TO_DATE method

Comment: I tried but still not getting the record.

Comment: @apomene Can you please write the query.

Comment: I tried with this : select * from business_details where business_date between to_date('12-JUN-18 21:15:13 ', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date(' 25-JUN-18 18:15:32','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

Comment: Fix your schema and use `DATE` instead of `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Seeing as it's Oracle, you're better off looking for a new job.

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing dates as strings, but assuming you are stuck with that and can't fix the schema, what format are those strings? (Hopefully a single format, and they are all correct - one reason *not* to use strings is there could be multiple formats and things that are ambiguous or won't convert to an actual date at all). Sample data from the table would be helpful, and can you add the actual column definition (from `describe`) just to confirm what you're dealing with.

Comment: It's production table. I won't be able to make any changes.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi Do you have any advice/suggestions from your side for new job ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in table **business_details** you have an column **date** or something like that.

Than use something like this:

```
select business_date from business_details
where date between TO_DATE ('12-JUN-18 21:15:13','dd-MM-yy hh:mi:ss') 
               AND TO_DATE ('25-JUN-18 18:15:32','dd-MM-yy hh:mi:ss');
```

Comment: This needs to use `HH24` rather than `HH`, and `MON` would be better than `MM`. Isn't the `business_date` the relevant column - why do you think there's another column to filter on?

Comment: I`m guessing, but you are right the statement should be written for business_date.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `business_date` is actually a string in the format you've shown (and it isn't really a date your client is just showing in that format), you need to convert that to a date type, as well as converting the string literals.

```
select *
from business_details
where to_date(business_date, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
  between to_date('12-JUN-18 21:15:13', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
      and to_date('25-JUN-18 18:15:32', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS');
```

The format model you tried to use in a comment did this:

```
to_date('12-JUN-18 21:15:13', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

is using `MM` rather than `MON`, which works anyway by default - although using month numbers is safer anyway as they aren't dependent on your session language. But more importantly it uses `YYYY`. If you pass a 2-digit value like 18 and try to convert with `YYYY` you get the wrong year:

```
select to_date('12-JUN-18 21:15:13', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') form dual;

TO_DATE('12-JUN-182
-------------------
0018-06-12 21:15:13
```

In your version your `business_date` was being converted implicitly so would use NLS settings, which are presumably using `RR` already. But that means you were comparing a date in 2018 with a range in 0018, which is why nothing matched.

---

You could also use timestamp literals for the fixed values (unless those strings are actually being passed in from somewhere else):

```
select *
from business_details
where to_date(business_date, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
  between cast(timestamp '2018-06-12 21:15:13' as date)
      and cast(timestamp '2018-06-25 18:15:32' as date);
```